# Is there a `sh` equivalent to bash's `<<<' redirection operator?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to execute an `at` command from a cgi script.  The script is executed as the default Apache2 user on Ubuntu (`www-data`) but the default shell is `/bin/sh` and not `bash`.   Aside from security issues of running `at` as `www-data` (see my other [question](https://serverfault.com/q/556332/5592)), I could change the default shell, but I'm wondering, ***is there a more portable way to write this `bash` friendly command?***

```
at now + 5 minutes <<< 'python my_script.py data_arg'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo 'python my_script.py data_arg' | at now + 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 5):

`<<<` is also just a shortcut for a single-line here document.

```
at now + 5 minutes <<EOF
python my_script.py data_arg
EOF
```